# Use Arc Welder as High Current PSU

Tags: power-supply, high-current

I have a dc arc welder that can give about 50v 20 - 120 amp output.
My question is can i use it as high current psu for example using it for ZVS driver or induction heater that need high current?
Thanks

Comment: Any power source should be no problem. Just make sure you are still in supported voltage range. More amps are better.

Comment: Also, make sure that current rating is *continuous* as opposed to pulsed.

Comment: Keep in mind that most portable welders are only rated for a very low duty cycle -- something like 10%, as opposed to the 100% that you would need for a power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think it would be right to determine what kind of welder you have as they are classified in two types:

1. Constant current (CC)

> a constant current machine varies its output voltage to maintain a steady current

2. Constant voltage (CV)

> a constant voltage machine will fluctuate its output current to maintain a set voltage

By your description, I assume you have a constant voltage welder. So, it is possible to make a power supply from your welder.

For more information you can go to:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welding_power_supply